# Virtualbox: Separate remote access from VM's internet access

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, routing

I'd like to access a Windows 7 VM from my fixed LAN via VRDP (VM is configured for remote access), but I'd like to have all the applications within the VM use a separate WiFi connection. I have a USB WiFi adapter connected to the host which gets connected to the VM at startup.

So basically, all traffic from within the VM should be routed through the WiFi Network while accessing the VM via VRDP should be done from the fixed LAN the host uses.

Is this possible and can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible.
In VirtualBox settings for the VM:

- disable all network adapters
- add USB filter for your USB Wi-Fi adapter (you already did it)
- enable remote screen (you already did it)

Comment: Hey, many thanks! It does work now. I totally misunderstood how VRDP works and did not know that you connect to the host machine via RDP.

Comment: +1 Simple, complete, accepted by the OP and posted just six minutes after the question!